# PyTube: PrivateVideo exception not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, except, pytube

I wrote a code that will print all videos' name on the playlist. The problem is when it tries to print the name of the video that is private. I wrote an exception from Github that the owner wrote but it still doesn't work. It should skip this one video and go to another one but it doesn't and the program crashes. Here is my code:

```
import pytube
from pytube.exceptions import VideoPrivate

pl = pytube.Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB1PGaMZkETOixDfsnKIOkfJS_cToCHSt")


for video in pl.videos:
    try:
        print(video.title)
    except VideoPrivate:
        continue
```

Error output:

```
python playlist.py
One Direction - Steal My Girl
One Direction - Drag Me Down (Official Video)
One Direction - Story of My Life
One Direction - Night Changes
One Direction - Perfect (Official Video)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playlist.py", line 6, in <module>
    for video in pl.videos:
  File "C:\Users\Elton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 222, in videos
    yield from (YouTube(url) for url in self.video_urls)
  File "C:\Users\Elton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 222, in <genexpr>
    yield from (YouTube(url) for url in self.video_urls)
  File "C:\Users\Elton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\Elton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 203, in prefetch
    self.check_availability()
  File "C:\Users\Elton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 137, in check_availability
    raise VideoPrivate(video_id=self.video_id)
pytube.exceptions.VideoPrivate: 8fGmghrkLco is a private video
```

Comment: The link return it does not exist, can provide a link that works?

Comment: code edited now it should work
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB1PGaMZkETOixDfsnKIOkfJS_cToCHSt

Comment: The exception is being raise when you iterate through the list. The result is ```yield``` one by one and there is a check prior return the next item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is generated outside of the try/catch.
It is actually being raised when the next item of `pl.videos` is yield.

```
@property
def videos(self) -> Iterable[YouTube]:
    """Yields YouTube objects of videos in this playlist

    :Yields: YouTube
    """
    yield from (YouTube(url) for url in self.video_urls)
```

Instead of calling videos, you may use `video_urls`

```
for video in pl.video_urls:
    try:
        print(YouTube(video).title)
    except VideoUnavailable:
        continue
```

Here we are using `VideoUnavailable` which is the baseClass for `VideoPrivate`

You will need the following imports:

```
import pytube
from pytube.exceptions import VideoUnavailable
from pytube import YouTube
```

Output:

```
One Direction - Steal My Girl
One Direction - Drag Me Down (Official Video)
One Direction - Story of My Life
One Direction - Night Changes
One Direction - Perfect (Official Video)
One Direction - You & I
```